# zsh substitutions: (P) and ::= operators interaction

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, zsh

Can someone explain to me the result of the following script in zsh:

```
#!/bin/zsh
var1=var2
var2=first
var3=second
echo var1="$var1"
echo var2="$var2"
echo var3="$var3"
echo '${${(P)var1::=var3}}'="${${(P)var1::=var3}}"
echo var1="$var1"
echo var2="$var2"
echo var3="$var3"
echo ------------
var1=var2
var2=first
var3=second
echo var1="$var1"
echo var2="$var2"
echo var3="$var3"
echo '${(P)var1::=var3}'="${(P)var1::=var3}"
echo var1="$var1"
echo var2="$var2"
echo var3="$var3"
```

Result:

```
var1=var2
var2=first
var3=second
${${(P)var1::=var3}}=second
var1=var2
var2=var3
var3=second
------------
var1=var2
var2=first
var3=second
${(P)var1::=var3}=var3
var1=var2
var2=var3
var3=second
```

As far as I understand the zsh manual (14.3.2 Rules), the execution of the first section (above ------) should be the following:

1. Point 7 (apply the ::= operator) (set var1 to var3)
2. Point 25 (apply the (P) operator) (dereference var1, get var3)
3. Output the value of var3: 'second'

These steps agree with the following line in the result:

```
${${(P)var1::=var3}}=second
```

But why in the result the following lines appear:

```
var1=var2
var2=var3
```

instead of the expected:

```
var1=var3
var2=first
```

The execution of the second section (below ----) should be (according to the manual):

1. Point 4 (apply the (P) operator) (dereference var1, get var2)
2. Point 7 (apply the ::= operator) (set var2 to var3)
3. Output the value of var2: 'var3'

The results of this section match the explanation above perfectly, so the problem is only with the first section.

Answer (score 0):

You skipped rule 1: nested substitution. Given `${${(P)var1::=var3}}=second`, rule 1 first (recursively) evaluates `${(P)var1::=var3}`, which starts by applying rule 4 to turn that into `${first::=var3}`. *Then* you can apply rule 7 to evaluate the `::=` operator. Once that is done, you go back to evaluating the outer `${...}`.

Comment: Rule 4 is only applied at the outermost level of nesting. "At the outermost level of nesting only, the '(P)' flag is applied." Besides that, please, check the second section which actually uses rule 4. The results are different.

Comment: But when rule 1 is applied to recursively evaluate a nested substitution, the `(P)` *is* at the outermost level of the *that* substitution. I think rule 25 applies to a different situation (which unfortunately no example of which is provided in the man page).